# Spatial Index on an InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, myisam, spatial

I have a database which is in InnoDB, because I wanted consistency (cascading delete).

Now, I want to use spatial indexes for selecting rows ordered by geometric distance.

However, spatial indexes require MyISAM. What is the best thing to do?

The best I could think of is to put the location in a separate MyISAM table and join the InnoDB table with it? (Note that I have removed the spatial magic from the statement to simplify things.)

```
select * from inno join isam using (id) order by isam.distance
```

Other solutions?

Comment: See my answer for an update.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the best I think. You have the benefit of both InnoDB (referential integrity) and MyISAM (spatial indexes.)

The only technical difficulty is to ensure that the MyISAM table is synchronized with the InnoDB one. This can be done either with triggers or by stored procedures (so every operation on the InnoDB table is done through a procedure.)

Another "benefit" is that since the coordinate values are duplicated at both tables, you can skip backing up the MyISAM table (or backing up separately) and have a procedure to recreate it after a database restore. You probably need a procedure to check periodically that that the two tables are in sync, too.

To speed up queries that need the spatial index - and if the table is not huge - you can make sure that the index is loaded in memory in advance, even in a separate cache. See [`LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-index.html) and [Multiple Key Caches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-key-caches.html)

Comment: Why would you suggest duplicating the location in both tables, rather than keeping it just in the MyISAM table where it is required?

Comment: Because myisam tables can crash and you can lose data.

Comment: And backing up only 1 type of tables is easier than dealing with 2 types, both myisam and innodb.

Comment: How does is backing up two database types problematic?

Comment: It's not problematic. But there are several ways to take a backup and many of those programs/ways work differently with the different engines. For example, with MyISAM, you can simply stop the mysql service and copy the files. You can't do that with InnoDB tables.

Comment: Note that MySQL 5.7 will have support for spatial indexes in INNODB tables, as evidenced by the recent lab releases.

Answer (score 1):

## MySQL 5.7+

In [MySQL 5.7, InnoDB got Spatial Indexes, from *What Is New in MySQL 5.7*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-additions)

> InnoDB now supports MySQL-supported spatial data types. Prior to this release, InnoDB would store spatial data as binary `BLOB` data. `BLOB` remains the underlying data type but spatial data types are now mapped to a new InnoDB internal data type, `DATA_GEOMETRY`.

I believe this was part of the [rewrite/refactor that brought in Boost](https://mysqlserverteam.com/why-boost-geometry-in-mysql/)

See also,

- [Using Spatial Indexes in MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-spatial-indexes.html)